# what will happen in my website when i changed the current theme with new one?

Tags: wordpress

1) Can i change the theme of wordpress in this site

www.lenews.info

with this,

http://quanticalabs.com/wp_themes/pressroom/home-style-6/

2)if i do it i lost something of image article format etc??

i need to change the theme but i don't know if i do it, what happen in the site

3) if i change the template? i want the same format of plugin and component, can anyone help me with this?

Presently I am using a wordpress theme.

- I want to change it to something better. But I am afraid, if I change
  the theme,
- I will lose all my contents that includes Posts, Pictures,
  Categories, Tags.
- I am not at all aware of this fact. Need some help.

Tell me if what I am afraid of is really going to happen if I change or not.
What are the pre-steps that I can take to keep all my contents uploaded the same way they were before.

I already have a daily backup system using WP Backup plugin.What else?
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Good habit is backup before do changes.

Checklist: 6 Things You MUST DO Before Changing WordPress Themes

1. Take Notes on Your Current Theme

   Go through your theme files and note down all additional code that you added. You also want to check your current theme’s load time because this way you can compare the two. Go to a site like [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) Tools or use YSlow to test out different pages (Yes different pages, not just the homepage).
2. Be cautious of the Sidebars

   If you are using a widget-enabled theme, and you switch to a theme that is not widget-ready, then you will lose all of that. If you are using a widget-enabled WordPress theme, then this is not an issue.
   Also anything that you modify in sidebar.php file of your old theme, will be overwritten. So make sure that you add those codes in the new theme sidebar.
3. Backup!!

   You never have anything to lose by creating a backup. As a precautionary measure, you should backup all of your theme files, plugins, and the database.

   4.Testing all functionality and plugins

   Once you have the new theme activated, you need to make sure that you retain all the functionality and plugins still work. Try out all the features including but not limited to the commenting process, single post pages, search, 404 page, archive page, contact page etc. Make sure all of your widgets are still there and are working.
4. Cross Browser Compatibility
   Test your site in all browsers you have access to. Browsers have a tendency of rendering things differently.
5. Maintenance Mode
   You probably don’t want your users to see while you are making the switch because they will end up seeing a broken site or such. It is best to turn on Maintenance mode for 15 – 20 minutes that it may take you to make sure that everything is working properly. Once you have setup Maintenance mode, you are good to go ahead and activate the new theme.